# ASP.NET5 beta8 IServiceCollection changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

After updating my project to recently released ASP.NET 5 beta8 I've found that `IServiceCollection` no longer contains definition for `ConfigureIdentity` and `ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie`.

So previously written code like

```
services.ConfigureIdentity(o =>
    {
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
    });

services.ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie(o => o.LoginPath = "/Admin/Users/Login");
```

can't be compiled anymore.

Google search brings no result, I suppose it is because only one day has passed since beta8 release.

Has anyone found workaround for this? How should identity options be configured in beta8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Configure*` methods are removed and the `Add*` methods now accept an `Action<TOptions>`:

```
services.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
    o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Admin/Users/Login";
});
```

Not exactly, but partially related: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/71

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Hope it will be helpful to someone else experiencing such a migration problems.